# Dynamically set router-outlet name

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to dynamically set the name of a router-outlet in angular 2? 
I need to create a generic component that contains a router-outlet.

Template example :

```
<nav class="nav menu">
    <a *ngFor="let navRoute of navigationRoutes" class="nav-link" [class.selected]="navRoute.isActive" (click)="onActivated(navRoute.route)">{{navRoute.header}}</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet name=[[DO SOME BINDING HERE]]></router-outlet>
```

navigationRoutes & name are component @inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>As far as I know this works since a while</strike>

```
<router-outlet [name]="propertyWithOutletName"></router-outlet>
```

There was an attempt to implement it but it wasn't completed.

https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/12550

Comment: I've got a "Template parse errors" when I add [ ] to the name attribute.

Comment: Then you are probably missing the `RouterModule` in `imports` of the current module.

Comment: I've importer the RouterModule in my module and still have the issue. Anything else?

Comment: This is the message : "Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of 'router-outlet'."

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. That's not yet supported. See my updated answer.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer: Facing the same problem. Any update on this issue? Is this supported now? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Nothing I know of.

Answer (score 5):

This is so frustrating. I really wish we could get a real solution. Here is my horrible hack, which works in this case because I only have three outlets: a, b, and c. My use case is that I have a three panel system with auxiliary urls and child routes. My "solution" would fall flat if I ever had a system where there was an arbitrary number of named outlets, or if the router outlet names could change dynamically.

What can we do to get on angular's case to get this fixed?

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-router-outlet',
  template: `
    <router-outlet 
      *ngIf="route.outlet === 'a'"
      name="a"
    ></router-outlet>
    <router-outlet 
      *ngIf="route.outlet === 'b'"
      name="b"
    ></router-outlet>
    <router-outlet 
      *ngIf="route.outlet === 'c'"
      name="c"
    ></router-outlet>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class RouterOutletComponent {
  constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) {}
}
```